# Connection timeout expired

Tags: vb.net

I am working for a windows form application in VB so when I installed application on a client PC that worked properly but when I install it on other client PC when client open the application, program encounter to problem and says :
**"Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.
Initialization = 15492;
Handshake 10647"**
help me to solve this problem
regards.

Comment: Please provide the full error details

Comment: This site is for specific coding issues. If you're told that a connection timeout has occurred then there's not an issue with your code. Search for the error message on the web and you'll likely find information specific to that, which will likely involve configuration changes to the app, the database server or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Connection Timeout occur basically in such a way,

**1.Increase the Connection Timeout time**

```
     Connection Timeout=1000
```

or

we can assign this timeout period in web.config file aslo.

**2.Set connnection TimeOut as Zero.** 
      System will wait until response from the Database or Stored Procedure

Using dbConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbConnStr)

Using SQLComm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLCommQry, dbConn)

SQLComm.CommandTimeout = 0

**3.Use Indexing for your Database**  For increase the data fetching performance.